# Updating the lower bound of a semi continuous variable no longer keeps it semi-continuous

Tags: java, cplex

I created a CPLEX semi-continuous variable and later updated its lower bound value. The variable was no longer treated as semi-continuous.

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();
IloNumVar x1=cplex.semiContVar(10, Double.MAX_VALUE,IloNumVarType.Float,"x1");
IloNumVar x2 = cplex.numVar(10, Double.MAX_VALUE,IloNumVarType.Float,"x2");
//If below line is commented, variable x1 is treated as semi continuous
x1.setLB(10);
objective.addTerm(x1, 4);
objective.addTerm(x2, 2);
cplex.addMinimize(objective);
cplex.lowerBound(x1..getVar().setLB(arg0);
cplex.solve();
if (cplex.solve()) {
    cplex.exportModel("Test2Variables.lp");
    System.out.println(cplex.getObjValue());
}
```

I expect the output to be 20, but the actual output is 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got the solution:

While setting lower bound i used : ((IloSemiContVar)x1).setSemiContLB(10);

This solved the problem.

Comment: It would be cleaner to declare `x1` as an `IloSemiConVar` instead of an IloNumVar. You would then not need to cast it to use `setSemiContLB()`.